# Using load balancer to terminate Kafka/SSL connections

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, load-balancing

We have two Kafka nodes and for reasons outside the scope of this question, would like to set up a load balancer to terminate SSL with producers (clients). The SSL cert hosted by the load balancer will be signed by trusted/root CA that clients should natively trust.

So the connection would look like:

```
Kafka Producers <---SSL/Port 9094--> Load Balancer <---TCP/Port 9092 ---> Kafka Node
```

Is this possible to do, or does Kafka somehow require SSL to be setup directly on the Kafka servers themselves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Kafka has its own internal load balancing protocol, and adding any 3rd party balancer in between Kafka clients and their brokers interferes with this protocol and causes very strange behavior.

**Don't do this.**

My motivation for wanting to do this was because I had failed to get SSL properly working between clients and brokers, and I thought terminating SSL at a load balancer, and then allowing plaintext communication between balancer and brokers would solve my issue. **It did not. Don't do this.**

Either:

1. Figure out how to get SSL working between clients and brokers (the official Kafka user mailing list was *excellent* at helping me achieve this); or
2. Don't require/support an SSL connection; or
3. Put a web service in front of your Kafka

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can totally do this and I'm going to use AWS's ELB as the example which I set it up for.

We had a Kafka cluster where producers/consumers within the cluster used a "private" listener, and we also had producers/consumers in public that used a "public" listener. Therefore we had to secure the public producer/consumer traffic with SSL. The Kafka cluster is behind an ELB, and SSL termination happens at the ELB after receiving traffic from the public producers/consumers.

The key props to set for the broker are (note these are env vars for docker container):

```
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${BROKER_NODE_PRIVATE_HOST}:9092,CLIENT://${ELB_DNS}:9093
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${BROKER_NODE_PRIVATE_HOST}:9092,CLIENT://${BROKER_NODE_PRIVATE_HOST}:9093
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT
```

Now, for the public producers/consumers, the key prop to set is

```
props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
```

Note that even though the public Kafka clients use SSL, before it gets to the broker the SSL is terminated within the ELB, and therefore the Kafka cluster can just operate with PLAINTEXT. Also, the public Kafka clients need to connect the ELB_DNS.

I'm not going to cover in detail how the ELB and certs are setup, but you'll just need to have the ELB listeners have TLS enabled and the relevant cert(s) applied. In our case, we had listeners forward traffic to the Kafka broker instance at 9093 and 8081 (schema registry).

Finally, if you're using a schema registry, make sure to remember to change the authority from http to https.